# Does 64 bit ActiveX exist?

Tags: com, 64-bit, activex

Question may sounds strange but I want to make this question clear.

Some people talk about 64 bit Active-X components 
[64 bit COM(ActiveX) server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513566/64-bit-comactivex-server)

while others claim there is no 64x COM implementation 
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/64-bit-activex-vs-windows-forms-t3764967.html

Who is right? Can I implement 64-bit Active-X (dll COM server) ?

Comment: The PCReview statement is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

64-bit COM is alive and well on the 64-bit version of Windows.  It wouldn't have Windows Explorer if COM was dead.  And the many, many other Windows component that depend on COM.  There's nothing in x64 code that could prevent COM from working.

Comment: There does remain the constraint that 64-bit host processes cannot load 32-bit in-proc servers, and vice versa. In-proc servers must match the bitness of the host process.

Comment: That's not a COM specific constraint, doesn't work on regular DLLs either.

Comment: True. I was just giving the original claim the benefit of the doubt and trying to come up with a way a true statement might be somehow misconstrued though a chain of whispers into what finally came out the other side.

Answer (score 1):

You can write 64bit ActiveX controls for IE, but be aware they will only run in 64bit IE.

Also be aware 32bit IE is the default for users when they click the IE icon, even on 64bit Windows.

Comment: How do I run 64 bit activex control in IE? I have raised a question on same here: http://superuser.com/questions/1123971/running-64-bit-ie-tab-process-on-windows-7 If possible, can you answer the same?

Comment: Sorry man, I have no idea.  It used to be simpler, but I got out of the browser plugin development business a long time ago so my knowledge is out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. will do some more searching :)